# Does anyone know the background battle music playing in the sci-fi anime "Sekirei"?

Tags: music-identification, sekirei

For years now, I've tried checking compilations of the original *Sekirei* sound track to find it, but no luck. I've included a short clip of a fight scene where the music starts, here:

Does anyone have an idea of the track's name, and where it might be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The track is called "Uka", by Hiroaki Sano:

https://mp3.pm/song/133063155/Hiroaki_Sano_-_Uka/

[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eP42OgJ19p0)

[image]

Comment: I should have known... Hiroaki-San is one of my *favorite* Japanese composers; his work on **Blue Exorcist** ( _Me and Creed_ ) and **Seraph of the End** ( _scapeGoat_ ) are two of my all time top instrumental pieces. Now, I have a third. Thank you, thank you, THANK YOU for this, friend! Well done! Could I possibly ask your help on another? None anime; it's from the Live action film *King of Fighters.* been looking for a full copy of that song for 2 years.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Do you have that second question posted?

Comment: Nope, but I'll send the small bit I have for it here for you.

Comment: It's called _Sacred Calls,_ from the film's opening. Written by Ayuko Tanaka Music by Shogo Ohnishi Vocals by Yuna Additional Vocals by Ayuko Tanaka & Lisa Takahashi. You can find it on youtube, in part. Looking for a full version of the song.

Comment: I see, will look for that too

Comment: Seems that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxxiOmxlRqI is the only more or less full version.

Comment: I know; it's frustrating. I thought I might be able to buy it on Amazon, but no go. If there was any way to check the original Japanese company or find someone who owns the OST, then it would be easy. Not sure where to go online to search specificaslly, but I'm curious about this full song.